# A boolen attribute or another table with FK

Tags: sql, relational-database

I'm in a a junior level database theory class. And we were given an assignment to create a database using sql's ddl. Any way, we were given a word problem and it describes a leader of hunters, it must belong to an elite group having killed more 100,000 zombies (cause zombie problems are awesome). The problem is to create this table or tables in the DDL. So I was planning on having a boolean field on the hunters table to indicate if the object was the leader or not. So every hunter would have an attribute set to false, except for one which would be true, and he would have to have killed 100,000 zombies. Another students solution was to create another table, with a FK to a hunter that would be the leader. Which method would be better? And why?

Answer (score 1):

The boolean flag is better because it's simpler and doesn't demand a join to a table with a single row